# How to count 1st duplicates value in array in Java

Tags: java

I have taken array  `int[] a = {33,33,5,5,9,8,9,9};` In this array so many values are duplicates means 33 comes twice & 5 also comes twice & 9 comes three times.
But I want to count the first value which is duplicate means 33 is first value which comes twice so answer would be 2.

I try:

```
public class FindFirstDuplicate
{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int c=0;
    int[] a = {33,33,5,5,9,8,9,9};

    outerloop:
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j< a.length; j++)
        {
            if(a[i] == a[j])
            {
                System.out.println(a[i]); //Duplicate value
                c++;
                break outerloop;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.print("Count: "+c);

    }
}
```

Output:
33
1

Comment: and your efforts are?Please try something this is for your benifit dont rely on other person logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {33,33,5,5,9,8,9,9};
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            int c=1; // we already found one. 
                     // and we initialize this counter inside the loop, 
                     // so that it is reset for each new starting number.
            for(int j = i+1; j< a.length; j++) // we're starting from next number (reason we start with c=1)
            {
                if(a[i] == a[j])
                    c++;

            }
            if(c > 0) {
                System.out.println("First uplicate value: "+ a[i] + " Count: " + c);
                break;      // we have to break out of the outer loop, 
                            // so the inner loop can finish counting duplicates
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
int[] numbers = {33, 33, 5, 5, 9, 8, 9, 9};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++) {
   if (!set.add(number[i])) {
        System.out.println("first duplicate is " + number[i] + " and index is " + i);
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't disagree with the general approach of using a set, but note that the answer OP is looking for is an array index (+1): "so answer would be 2".

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks! That was simple and have modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the array are non-negative and reasonably small, you can use a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) to store whether or not you have seen a value previously:

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
  if (bits.get(numbers[i])) {
    System.out.println("first duplicate at " + i + ": " + numbers[i]);
    break;
  }
  bits.set(numbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this out:

```
int[] a = {33,33,5,5,9,8,9,9};
Integer[] uniques = new Integer[a.length];
Integer[] counts = new Integer[a.length];
int len = 0;
for(int num : a){
   boolean matched = false;
   for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
      if(num == uniques[i].intValue()){
         matched = true;
         counts[i] = new Integer(counts[i]+1);
         break;
      }
   }
   if(!matched){
      uniques[len] = new Integer(num);
      counts[i] = new Integer(1);
      len++;
   }
}
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
   if(counts[i].intValue() > 1){
      System.out.println("first duplicate is " + uniques[i] + " and number of times it appears " + counts[i]);
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: There would be a lot of unnecessary operations done in your program ... If you could even compile it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you exit both loops after the first duplicate is found, so any other occurences of the element would be ignored.

Also you start with `c = 0`. When you get to the second occurence, `c` will be incremented and be `1`, not `2`.

To count all elements simply change the loop condition of the outer loop and remove the `break`:

```
int c = 1;
int i;
for(i = 0; (c == 1) && (i < a.length); i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++)
    {
        if(a[i] == a[j])
        {
            c++;
        }
    }

}

System.out.println(a[i]); //Duplicate value
System.out.print("Count: "+c); // maybe do something else, if c == 1 (no duplicates)???
```

However [SMA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589793/2991525) describes a more performant way (for arbitrary input arrays) of finding the first duplicate. Once you found the second occurence of the first duplicate, you'd only need to count the number of occurences in the rest of the array to get the final count.